# УгнОва чи УгнЕва?

Tags: відмінювання, родовий-відмінок

Нещодавно мала чудову можливість відвідати найменше місто України- Угнів. Шукаючи інформацію про це місто натрапила на двояке відмінювання цієї географічної назви- **[УгнОва](https://m-a-d-m-a-x.livejournal.com/173981.html) і [УгнЕва](https://ua.igotoworld.com/ua/poi_object/66713_istoriko-kraevedcheskiy-muzey-ugnev.htm)**. Місцеві жителі, за спостереженням, вживають форму **УгнОва**.

Чи в цьому випадку відмінювання зберігається як [Канів](https://studopedia.ru/16_46774_zrazki-vidminyuvannya-geografichnih-nazv.html), тобто правильна форма **УгнЕва**. Чи, можливо, є польський вплив на походження назви **UhnOv** і відповідно відмінювання ?

Отже, як правильно вживати **УгнЕва чи УгнОва**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**У́гнів** — іменник чоловічого роду

| відмінок | однина |
| --- | --- |
| *називний* | У́гнів |
| *родовий* | **[У́гнева](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B2)** |
| *давальний* | У́гневу |
| *знахідний* | У́гнів |
| *орудний* | У́гневом |
| *місцевий* | У́гневі, У́гневу |
| *кличний* | У́гневе |